# How to force use of default conda channels for package install without setting channel priority

Tags: python, conda

I have a `.condarc` like so:

```
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - http://conda.anaconda.org/gurobi
  - defaults
```

I have a setup script for my conda-environment like so:

```
conda create -y -n myenv python=3.7
source activate myenv

conda install -y keras
conda install -y matplotlib

...

conda deactivate
```

I just realized that this script stopped working as it used to (meaning the setup-script still ran correctly, but the environment did not behave as previously). I found out that this is likely due to my modified `.condarc`, because after removing the first two channel entries (leaving only `- defaults`), it worked again.

I know I can set channel priorities. I also know that I can specify install channels with the `-C` option (e.g. `conda install -C conda-forge`). But how would I specify the use of default-channels to `conda install` without changing the priorities?
Essentially, I want something like this, which does not work:

```
conda install -C defaults -y keras
```

I want this, so that my script is self-contained, has reproducible behavior, and does not have to mess with its environment (e.g. by setting the priorities from inside the script).

Comment: Can you try `conda install -c defaults` (small `c`) and report with more detail what `which does not work:` means? Do you get an error or otherwise non-expected behaviour

Comment: This should work:  `conda install -c defaults --override-channels <pkg-name>`

Comment: ugh. yes, it was `-C` vs. `-c`. ouch. thanks for pointing that out. it works now.

Comment: As an aside, you should specify the dependencies in an environment.yml file and create the environment from that. It has multiple benefits, one of those is that you can set the channels for that particular environment.